# How do I search and display data to a cell on excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know the code that displays a search result on excel? Currently, my code only searches and highlights my data, but I want it to be displayed in a particular cell. I want the search result of the city to be displayed in cell H5 as given in the link http://postimg.org/image/xwhb021m3/

This is my current code:

```
Sub search()
    Dim City As String, CellName As String
    City = InputBox("Please enter the city to start search", "Search Input")
    If City <> "" Then
        Range("B4").Select
        For Indx = 0 To G - 1
            If ActiveCell.Offset(Indx, 0).Value = City Then
                CellName = "B" & LTrim(str(4 + Indx))
                Range(CellName).Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Indx
        If Indx = G Then
            Beep
            MsgBox "The city was not found", , "Not Found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Search cannot start" & vbCrLf & _
            "Because there is no input", , "Search Aborted"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! So when you search for Tokyo and it is found, you want H5 to be "Tokyo"? And if you search for another city after, that should go to H6? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want all my results to be displayed in cell H5.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Dennis!

It is not effective to get user to type in a city and look for exact match including cases but anyway, you can do will below code (there are far better ways to search cell values). With your approach (checking values cell by cell), understand the code below.

Revised code also sets formula to point to the population.

**NOTE:** You need to implement a Sub to remove results from previous search!

```
Sub SearchCity()
    Dim sSearchFor As String, oRngResult As Range, oRngData As Range

    sSearchFor = Trim(InputBox("Please enter the city to start search", "Search Input"))
    If Len(sSearchFor) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search cannot start" & vbCrLf & "Because there is no input", vbExclamation, "Search Aborted"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Initial cell locations
    Set oRngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B5") ' Data starts from this cell
    Set oRngResult = ActiveSheet.Range("H5") ' Results starts from this cell
    ' "Search" until cell is empty on the "data cell"
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRngData)
        ' Compare the data cell value with the typed string (convert to lowercase)
        If LCase(oRngData.Value) = LCase(sSearchFor) Then
            ' Exact spelling matched, store the address and move the results range to next row
            oRngResult.Value = Replace(oRngData.Address, "$", "") ' Cell Address for Population
            oRngResult.Offset(0,1).Formula = "=" & oRngData.Offset(0,3).Address ' 2012 Population column
            Set oRngResult = oRngResult.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Set oRngData = oRngData.Offset(1, 0) ' Move down to next row of data
    Loop
    Set oRngData = Nothing
    Set oRngResult = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Patrick! Thanks for the reply and advice. I want all my result of the name of the city to be displayed in cell H5 and the population in cell I5. Currently, all that is being displayed is the cell where the city is located in cell H5.

Comment: Hey @DennisTan, check the revised code and my **NOTE**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overdo it. An alternative would be to use the [`Find Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx) of the Range Object.

```
Dim City As String
City = InputBox("Please enter the city to start search", "Search Input")

If City <> "" Then
    With Sheets("SheetName") ' Always try to be explicit
        Dim c As Range
        ' You adjust this part to suit
        Set c = .Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Find(City, , , xlWhole) 
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            .Range("H5").Value2 = c.Value2
            ' Adjust Offset below to get the population column
            .Range("I5").Value2 = c.Offset(0, 1).Value2 
        Else
            MsgBox "The city was not found", , "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Search cannot start" & vbCrLf & _
        "Because there is no input", , "Search Aborted"
End If
```

If you use the built-in Method, it already returns the *Range Object*.
You can then work on that object to retrieve, change or store somewhere it's value.